# rasbian Stretch - wlan0 get configuration parameters - power management

Tags: power-management

How can I get the actual values of the TIMEOUT and PERIOD parameters?
It is explained how to change them, but it is not clear to me how to retrieve the configured values.

> COMMAND LINE: iwconfig - PARAMETER: power
>   man iwconfig
>   To set the period between wake ups, enter period `value'. [...]
>   Examples :
>   iwconfig wlan0 power period 2
>   iwconfig waln0 power 500m unicast
>   iwconfig wlan0 power timeout 300u all
>   iwconfig wlan0 power saving 3
>   iwconfig wlan0 power off

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What is your setup, what do you want to achieve, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi. The online manual related to 'iwconfig' command describes how to set timeout and period parameters. But before changing them I am interested in knowing how to retrieve their present values.